# Cannot deploy Spring Application on Tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat

I am facing following error while deploying webapp on Tomcat server. I am using Spring 2.5 and Tomcat 6 for the deployment.

```
[Tomcat-7]: Jun 10, 2020 5:14:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error while attempting to validate required application extensions
java.io.IOException: invalid header field
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateApplication(ExtensionValidator.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5468)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1007)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:639)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1296)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:2037)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[Tomcat-7]: Jun 10, 2020 5:14:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more components marked the context as not correctly configured
[Tomcat-7]: Jun 10, 2020 5:14:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/cheruvu-spring] startup failed due to previous errors
```

This is my manifest file:

Manifest-Version: 1.1.0
Class-Path:

I have also tried deploying the webapp on Tomcat 7 and 8, but same error occures everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your manifest is correct.  try remove the part after `1.1.0`.  you don't have a valid for the classpath. file should be

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 4.2.0 (Cool Dev)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html

Maybe this isn't good but i've never created a manifest file for any webapp with spring.  I haven't found a need for one yet...